# access context in getDerivedStateFromProps in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using class to use React.createContext

```
const config = React.createContext()

class MyApp extends Component {

  static contextType = TenantConfig

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(){
  this.context // I can't do this here
}

  render(){
    return <div>anything</div>
  }
}

MyApp.contextType = config
export default MyApp
```

How to access this.context in getDerivedStateFromProps?

Comment: Possibly duplicated `https://stackoverflow.com/q/56641669/5832644`

Comment: @tuan.tran not a duplicate, I want to compare value from the context in props of getDerivedStateFromProps

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `this` keyword in a static function.

You can always use `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` for any comparison.